# Ударение в слове "мизер"

Tags: фонетика

Всегда говорят "мИзер", но недавно узнал, что правильно "мизЕр". Это правда?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В слове **МИЗЕР** ударение может ставиться и *мИзер*, и *мизЕр* — в зависимости от смысла.

1. только: *миз**е**р*. При игре в преферанс: обязательство игрока не взять ни одной взятки.
2. только: *м**и**зер*. Разг. Очень малое, мизерное количество чего-л.
   *И такого мизера тебе жаль! Ограничиться мизером.* < Мизер, нареч. только: мизер. Совсем мало, почти ничего. *Соли осталось мизер*.

Comment: Не являюсь специалистом, но откуда-то вспоминаю, что нужно говорить "мизЕрный". А ведь прилагательное соответствует второму смыслу!  
Кстати, верно ли, что второй смысл слова "мизер" произошел от первого (как переносное значение)?  

Сама я скажу, конечно "мИзер", тем более, что в преферанс не играю :))

Comment: Нет - оба раза. Я вам в тексте ответил.

Comment: DocentI, вы правы. Можно говорить и "мизЕрный" и "мИзерный".

Comment: Серж, вы бы почитали другие ответы, прежде чем делать такие выводы. Говорить-то можно, только смысл разный. Да и сама Docentl не ставит так вопроса, что можно "и так, и так".

Answer (score 2):

Малое количество — ми́зер;
обязательство игрока в преферансе — мизе́р.

Answer (score 1):

Не буду спорить в отношении нормативности, но общаясь с заядлыми преферансистами очень редко слышал "мизЕр" от игроков не самого старшего возраста.

> Не являюсь специалистом, но откуда-то вспоминаю, что нужно говорить "мизЕрный". А ведь прилагательное соответствует второму смыслу!

Нет. К значению "недостаточный", "крайне малый" (это значение считаю основным) прилагательное - м**и**зерный.
Миз**е**рный - это только по отношению к преферансу (и ещё некоторым играм).

> Кстати, верно ли, что второй смысл слова "мизер" произошел от первого (как переносное значение)?

Нет. Просто слово "мизер" пришло в язык из английского, где произношение совпало с исходным латинским. Карточная же терминология на 99.99 основана на французской лексике.