# Ударение в слове мизерный

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно произносить слово мизерный? Может ли это слово встретиться на ЕГЭ?

Comment: Есть утвержденный список слов для задания А1 на ЕГЭ (орфоэпический словник). Слова "мизерный" среди них нет. Словник можно скачать [здесь][1]


  [1]: http://egeigia.ru/map-ege/195-zadaniya-ege/1387-orfo-slovnik-ege-2014

Comment: >Есть утвержденный список слов для задания А1  
  
Кем утвержденный? Не вижу в нем никаких на то указаний.
Впрочем, это только Истины ради. 
То, что такое слово **не должно** появляться на экзамене - понятно. Но у нас же ничему нельзя верить))).

Comment: Работниками ФИПИ (Федеральный институт педагогических измерений). Этот список существует третий год и означает только одно:  других слов в А1 на экзамене не будет. И не было. Последние два года. А раньше было сложнее.

Comment: Орфоэпический словник и другие методические материалы-это приложения к "Спецификациям" и "Кодификатору".Это серьёзные документы, им можно верить. И методичкам от Львова, например, т.к. он входит в состав комиссии, составляющей задания. Учитель-практик, ведущий подготовку к ЕГЭ, такие имена и приложения знает и никогда не задаст подобных вопросов("Кем утверждённый?").Информация даётся на специальных сайтах, например,http://www.ctege.info/ege-2014/ege-2014-izmeneniya-i-novovvedeniya-ege-v-2014-godu.html

http://blog-ege.livejournal.com/115968.html

Answer (score 3):

На ЕГЭ не даются слова с вариантным ударением,но в "Экзаменационных "ловушках"" есть орфоэпическая норма - мизЕрный , а мИзерный даётся как допустимый разговорный. В латинском языке miser (мИзэр) значило "бедный". "МизЕрный" - незначительный, ничтожный , слово  перекочевало к нам не напрямую из латыни, а через французское посредство. Во французском же произносят "мизЭр" (misere). Отсюда и колебания в ударении.Кстати, в английском языке  misery значит «страдание, мучение», словом miser называют человека, который живёт в нищенских условиях ради экономии и накопительства, скупца и скрягу, который ни за что не потратит зря ни малой толики.

http://newslab.ru/blog/388458

Comment: Боже, что это за источник?!
Я даже логику не могу понять. О каком колебании в ударении говорит автор, если сам же приводит **французский** вариант - и утверждает, на её основе единственную норму?! 
Нет, мне определенно ближе Аванесов, хоть он и не проводит разницу между значениями, считая "мИзерный" всего лишь допустимым.  
А что такое экзаменационные ловушки?!

Comment: "Зкзаменационные ловушки"- методическое пособие С.Ю.Ивановой. С учётом трудностей заданий на реальных экзаменах. И терия, и практика.

Comment: >"Зкзаменационные ловушки"- методическое пособие С.Ю.Ивановой.  
  
Это входит в список обязательной литературы?! 
Впрочем, ладно. Спасибо за информацию.

Answer (score 0):

Насчет ЕГЭ не знаю, а произносить можно двояко. 
Словари пока не договорились окончательно, какое ударение считать основным, какое - специальным. Но по крайней мере сходятся в том, что оба варианта возможны.

На мой вкус - и отчасти вопреки всем словарям: *в карточных играх единственно правильно миз**е**р, миз**е**рный, во всех остальных случаях рекомендуемый вариант - м**и**зер, м**и**зерный и допустимый - миз**е**р, миз**е**рный*.
Тут вот какая штука. Это слово попало в язык почти одновременно в XVIII-XIX веках разными путями, из английского и французского соответственно. В большинстве значений случаев английский вариант в силу большей распространенности потеснил французский,пусть и не до конца. Но карточная терминология того времени была сплошь французской - и нет причин это пересматривать.

А вопрос-то, оказывается, уже обсуждался...
[Ударение в слове "мизер"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/7226)

И вот ешё ссылка по теме.
http://www.rg.ru/2004/02/13/koroleva.html
Но тут надо иметь в виду, что это всего лишь Марина Королева, источник, может, и авторитетный, но никак не нормативный.